# No events emitted when running test in mocha

Tags: solidity, truffle, mocha

Good day, I'm new to blockchain and doing a university project. my contract file seems to be compiling but all my test cases are failing, saying no events emitted. I've included the test case and contract function.

Test Case:

```
// This script is designed to test the solidity smart contract - EduChain.sol -- and the various functions within
// Declare a variable and assign the compiled smart contract artifact
var EduChain = artifacts.require('EduChain')
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions')

contract('EduChain', function(accounts) {
    // Declare few constants and assign a few sample accounts generated by ganache-cli
    var sku = 1
    var upc = 1
    const ownerID = accounts[0]
    const originStudentID = accounts[0]
    const studentName = "John"
    const studentSurname = "Doe"
    const uniName = "TUT"
    const courseName = "Blockchain" // Course Applying for by person
    var personID = sku + upc
    const bookPrice = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") // Book Price
    const monthlyPrice = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") // Monthly Price
    const rentPrice = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") // Accommodation Price
    const feesPrice = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether") // University Fees Price
    // uint256 passRate; // Pass rate of the student
    var personState = 0 // Person State as represented in the enum above
    // address studentID; // Metamask-Ethereum address of the student
    const uniID = accounts[2] // Metamask-Ethereum address of the University
    const accommodationID = accounts[3]// Metamask-Ethereum address of the Accommodation
    const nsfasID = accounts[4]// Metamask-Ethereum address of Nsfas
    const emptyAddress = '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000'
   
    console.log("ganache-cli accounts used here...")
    console.log("Contract Owner: accounts[0] ", accounts[0])
    console.log("Student: accounts[1] ", accounts[1])
    console.log("University: accounts[2] ", accounts[2])
    console.log("Accommodation: accounts[3] ", accounts[3])
    console.log("Nsfas: accounts[4] ", accounts[4])
    
    // 1st Test
    it("Testing smart contract function applyUni() that allows a student to apply to university", async() => {
        const eduChain = await EduChain.deployed()
        await eduChain.addStudent(originStudentID)

        // Declare and Initialize a variable for event
        var eventEmitted = false

        // Watch the emitted event Applied_Uni()
        eduChain.Applied_Uni(null, (error, event)=> {
            eventEmitted = true;
        });

        // Mark a person as Applied_Uni by calling function applyUni()
        let result = await eduChain.applyUni(upc, originStudentID, studentName, studentSurname, courseName, uniName, uniID , {from: originStudentID})

        // Retrieve the just now saved person from blockchain by calling function fetchPerson()
        const resultBufferOne = await eduChain.fetchPersonBufferOne.call(upc)
        const resultBufferTwo = await eduChain.fetchPersonBufferTwo.call(upc)

        // Verify the result set
        console.log(resultBufferOne);
        console.log(resultBufferTwo);
        assert.equal(resultBufferOne[0], sku, 'Error: Invalid person SKU')
        assert.equal(resultBufferOne[1], upc, 'Error: Invalid person UPC')
        assert.equal(resultBufferOne[2], originStudentID, 'Error: Missing or Invalid ownerID')
        assert.equal(resultBufferOne[3], originStudentID, 'Error: Missing or Invalid originStudentID')
        assert.equal(resultBufferOne[4], studentName, 'Error: Missing or Invalid studentName')
        assert.equal(resultBufferOne[5], studentSurname, 'Error: Missing or Invalid studentSurname')
        assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[0], personID, 'Error: Invalid personID')
        assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[1], uniName, 'Error: Missing or Invalid uniName')
        assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[2], courseName, 'Error: Missing or Invalid courseName')
        // assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[3], bookPrice, 'Error: Missing or Invalid courseName')
        // assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[4], monthlyPrice, 'Error: Missing or Invalid courseName')
        // assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[5], rentPrice, 'Error: Missing or Invalid courseName')
        // assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[6], feesPrice, 'Error: Missing or Invalid courseName')
        assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[8], uniID, 'Error: Missing or Invalid uniID')
        assert.equal(resultBufferTwo[7], 0, 'Error: Invalid person State')
        assert.equal(eventEmitted, true, 'Invalid event emitted')
        truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, 'Applied_Uni');
    })
```

Below is the contract function:

```
    // Define a function 'applyUni' that allows a person to mark a student as 'Applied_Uni'
    function applyUni(
        uint256 _upc,
        address _originStudentID,
        string memory _studentName,
        string memory _studentSurname,
        // string memory _personID,
        string memory _courseName,
        string memory _uniName,
        address _uniID
        //string memory _productNotes
    ) public onlyStudent {
        // Add the new person as part of applied
        persons[_upc].upc = _upc;
        persons[_upc].sku = sku;
        // persons[_upc].ownerID = msg.sender;
        persons[_upc].ownerID = _originStudentID;
        persons[_upc].originStudentID = _originStudentID;
        persons[_upc].studentName = _studentName;
        persons[_upc].studentSurname = _studentSurname;
        persons[_upc].personID = _upc + sku; // Product ID is a combo of upc + sku
        persons[_upc].courseName = _courseName;
        persons[_upc].uniName = _uniName;
        persons[_upc].uniID = _uniID;
        persons[_upc].personState = State.Applied_Uni;

        // Increment sku
        sku = sku + 1;
        // Emit the appropriate event
        emit Applied_Uni(_upc);
    }
```

Github link: https://github.com/ashoktut/educhains

Answer (score 0):

You could check event emitting like this =>

```
 const tx = await eduChain.applyUni(...args)
 const receipt = await tx.wait()
 const event = receipt.events.find(e => e.event === 'Applied_Uni')
```